# Content Based Image Retrieval Resources

Tags: algorithm, cbir

I have seen many papers of CBIR (Content Based Image Retrival). I would like to find an ebook or some other resource with all the thoery and the explanation of the most important or famous algoritms in this area.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand, there really shouldn't be a book on CBIR because CBIR is the front end of image distance measure plus the backend of IR, such as TF-IDF. So I think you can look for a classic book on classic IR (such as this one: [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Information-Retrieval-Ricardo-Baeza-Yates/dp/020139829X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020139829X)) and other more diverse resource on image similarity measure. For the later it is usually also separate into feature extraction and statistics-driven models. I believe it is still an actively researched area. For the classical IR, you can also look at Salton et al.'s original paper http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=361220. Hope this helps!